# I am fetching friendly clear in .htaccess urls in php

Tags: php, .htaccess, mysqli, web-deployment

I'm developing a website using PHP. I'm trying to hide any PHP extension, using .htaccess.

This is my link urls for visiting an user profile :

```
<a class="nav-link" href="user/<?php echo"$username"; ?>"><i class="fa fa-user ispace"></i><?php echo"$username"; ?></a>
```

and this is my .htaccess rules:

```
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ profile.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But when I click on an user profile link, my bootstrap isn't loaded.

Also, the user header link redirects to www.mysitename.com/user/home and then shows a 404 error. How to fix this?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

To hide the .php extension:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

To hide the .html extension:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Put the .htaccess on the main Folder.

To test just do something like:

```
<a href="tests">Test go to .php file</a>
```

Should work.

Comment: @AkjonBerthoManus you just need to use the name file without the '.php' on the href and it should work with that .htaccess

Comment: But bro i want to change te file name by .htaccess because of my server security reason .

Comment: i want to make my site urls www.mysite.com/user/akjonberthomanush as like